# How to hide some html from IE 6-11 and MS Edge browser

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am working on web app which allow chrome and firefox only. For every access from IE 6-11 or MS Edge, there will be a **alert message** and **hide a `<form>...</form>` elements**. I used conditional comment.It can display the message in IE6-11 but not MS edge. The form does not hide in MS edge.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

```html
 <html>
 
 
 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
 <!--[if lte IE 9]> 
  <div>
    <font face="verdana" color="red" size="5">Internet Explorer is not supported. Please use Google Chrome/Firefox.</font>
  </div>
 <![endif]-->
   
 <![if (!IE)]>
        Show the form
        <form>...</form>
 <![endif]>
  
  
  
  </html>
```

Comment: Microsoft Edge isn't Internet Explorer, so I don't see the problem here. I'd be surprised if this was hidden from IE10 or IE11, though, considering they don't recognize conditional comments either.

Comment: why are using IE9 in the x-ua meta? why do you want to show content in some browsers but not others? The common design pattern is to code to standards and where necessary provide fallbacks in scripting and layout for features that the client browser does not support.... Include modernizer.js and jquery.js in your project, target IE11 and modern browsers only..... you should only use meta x-ua headers and meta on intranet sites.

Comment: My project targets chrome and firefox only. Thanks.

Comment: what features are you wanting to block from Edge? It is a _very_ different browser from IE. Anything that works in Chrome should work in Edge, for the vast majority of cases